# How to specify conditions on joined tables in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to do a query in in Rails with ActiveRecord that specifies some condition on a joined table. And i can't seem to get it to work, even though i follow the examples from here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

From the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org):

> `Client.joins(:orders).where(:orders => {:created_at => time_range})`

My database schema looks like this, with tables `scores`, `submissions` and `tasks`:

```
  create_table "scores", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "value"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "scores", ["user_id"], :name => "index_scores_on_user_id"

  create_table "submissions", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "task_id"
    t.integer  "score_id"
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "submissions", ["score_id"], :name => "index_submissions_on_score_id"
  add_index "submissions", ["task_id"], :name => "index_submissions_on_task_id"
  add_index "submissions", ["user_id"], :name => "index_submissions_on_user_id"

  create_table "tasks", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "episode_id"
    t.integer  "score"
    t.string   "key"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

So i want to do a query where I can find all "scores" that have a relation to a spesific task. Submission belongs to tasks and scores.

My query now looks like this:

```
Score.joins(:submission).where(:submission => {:task_id => 1})
```

This generates the following syntax:

```
SELECT "scores".* FROM "scores" INNER JOIN "submissions" ON "submissions"."score_id" = "scores"."id" WHERE "submission"."task_id" = 1
```

Which generates the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: submission.task_id
```

But there is a column `submission.task_id`, which you can see in the db schema. And i can do this successfully:

```
SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."task_id" = 1
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The name in the clause should be plural to reference the table name:

```
Score.joins(:submission).where(:submissions => {:task_id => 1})
```

Comment: In fact, according to the Rails guide snippet posted, so should the `joins` symbol.

Comment: @Chowlett, that is because they have a Many to Many relation, I only have a One to One, has_one, instad of has_many. That is also why I didn't catch the plural in referance to the table name i think.

Answer (score 16):

I find this to be easier.

```
Score.joins(:submission).merge(Submission.where(task_id: 1))
```

Answer (score 12):

The clause name should be plural to reference the table name.

```
Score.joins(:submission).where(submissions: { task_id: 1 })
```

If score has many submissions, the joins symbol should also be plural to reference the relation between Score and Submission.

```
Score.joins(:submissions).where(submissions: { task_id: 1 })
```

Answer (score 6):

A caveat: if you're using non-standard table names the above will fail like so:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "submissions"
```

To fix this, put `(joined-model-class).table_name` as a key in the `where` hash:

```
Score.joins(:submission).where(
  Submission.table_name => {task_id: 1}
)
```